# Adding images in OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy

You can add two images by OpenCV function, `cv2.add()` or simply by numpy operation, `res = img1 + img2`. Both images should be of same depth and type, or second image can just be a scalar value.
What should i use to compare their depth and type of images.i have studied about

```
img.dtype
img.type()
img.depth()
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scalar value is not an image, it is an scalar value.
If you add scalar value to an image, that value will be added to all the pixels in the image (If the image is a colored one, then that value will be added to all the pixels in all the BRG layers)

I don't know what you meant by depth of the image. If it is the number of layers that you are referring then YES, both images should have same depth. But not same type. Images with different types can be added together.

But sometimes there is no meaning of adding 2 images with different types. As a example an image with a `float` type has it's pixel values in the range [0, 1]. And an image with an `int` type has it's pixel values in the range [0, 255]. Therefore there is no meaning of adding these files without converting them into a same type.

You can compare depth (no of layers) and type of the image as follows.

```
img.dtype    # to compare the type
img.shape    # to compare the number of layers
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV uses `numpy` types for images. A one channel image with width `w` and height `h` is stored as a 2D array of size `h,w` and an image with N channels is stored by a 3d array of size `h,w,N`. You can access these values with `array.shape`. Similarly you can access the type with `array.dtype`.